# Node.JS Load Testing tools with thousand of virtual users

Tags: node.js, load-testing

The goal is to make a load test of the Node.JS server on AWS.

The server should support extremely high peaks of different users per second (20K) event more.
I tried a few load test tools like Artillery and LoadTest. Unfortunately didn't manage to get more than 3K VUs by setting up the Kuberense cluster of 16 cores with 64G in total.
The result was less than 60 VUs per pod within 100% CPU utilization. When I tried to get at least 200 VUs on 50 pods

Probably anyone an idea of less CPU-consuming load testing tools.

Comment: Somewhat related documentation on AWS side "Distributed Load Testing on AWS" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/distributed-load-testing-on-aws/distributed-load-testing-on-aws.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one physical (or virtual) server which doesn't scale it doesn't make a lot of sense to use container orchestration tools like k8s as it doesn't add any value and just consumes resources.

With regards to resource consumption by the load testing tool, there is a bare minimum which will always be required like:

- operating system thread footprint in memory
- request and response size
- extra resources required by the language runtime

From my previous experience [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/) provides the maximum throughput on minimal resources.

However depending on the nature of your test you might want to consider other tools, i.e. see [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) article for more options.

Narrow down the tools selection to the ones which support network protocols required for your application load testing and don't forget that the majority of tools assume performance tuning.

Also don't forget that the real users don't hammer the application non-stop, they need some time to ["think"](https://dzone.com/articles/performance-testing-with-a-think-time) between operations so first of all ensure that your virtual user behaves like a real user, it might be the case you just to need to make the workload more realistic and the current hardware/software setup will be sufficient

Comment: Thank you, Dmitri, your points are extremely helpful. a few corrections, the k8s setup consist of 4 virtual nodes. with the total resources of 16 cores and 64G. The throughput I manage to get was 3K requests when the server utilization was only 50% CPU. So I think I can get even better throughput, overcoming the client bottleneck